# How to use features with different lengths to fit one neural network model?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I want to use 1-dimentional features with varying length to train a neural network. For example:

10 features in group A: feature shape: (80000, 10) ; label shape: (80000, 1)

5 features in group B: feature shape: (200000, 5) ; label shape: (200000, 1)

As you can see, data in the two groups have different length. How to implement them all to fit the model?

I have an idea to do it by just fit the model one by one.

```
historyA = model.fit(feature_A , label_A, epochs=10)
historyB = model.fit(feature_B , label_B, epochs=10)
```

Thus the model was trained in two steps by two groups of data, but it may take longer computation time than necessary.
Does anyone consider this approach problematic or have a better idea?
Thank you so much!

Comment: Better to pad the smallest features vector to the largest's size.

Comment: If you meant by pad_sequences, it just appends constants (like 0) to the smallest size, but without giving a target label for each constant.  
@stateMachine